# Is it possible to filter the main loop to exclude posts from a specific category?

Tags: posts, multisite, filters

The question is the same as the title. I'm talking about the default loop on the blog page / home page.

I am using a network blog and must apply it to all blogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still are going to make use of `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query query vars before the main query actually runs. The blog page/homepage can be targeted with the `is_home()` conditional tag

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    is_home() // Only targets the home/blog page
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only targets the main query
    ) {
        // Works on build in taxonomy category, for custom taxonomies, use a tax_query
        $q->set( 'cat', -1 ); // Change with correct category ID, minus sign means remove
    }
}, PHP_MAX_INT ):
```

I would add this into a plugin which you can activate (*as Super Admin*) as a [network plugin across the entire network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#Plugins)

Comment: I appreciate your help in getting through these setup questions. Do you have an email I can contact you at? if I show you what I'm working on all my questions will be put into context. This should lead to better approaches me thinks.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but I do unfortunately not give out my personal info. I also just do this for fun so I do not take on projects etc. If you think a question is unclear, link to previous questions to add context to a new question